# Multiple SSH public keys into a single file

Tags: ssh, aix, ssh-keys

I'm trying to sftp to a host which acts as a load balancer and routes to 3 other systems based on round robin.

Our public key is setup on their systems. Yet, when ever I try to connect, I get prompted with a "Man in Middle attack" message asking us to verify the key finger print. To over come this I tried adding their public host key into .ssh2/hostkeys/key22_22_hostname.pub file.

Problem is I can't add 3 keys into this file, it seems to accept only one key?

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue or add 3 public keys into one key22_22_hostname.pub file?

This is on AIX system.

Answer (score 0):

How about cheat and copy the one system's keys to the others?  I know is sorta scummy but in this case, it might be appropriate.

I believe those keys are found in /etc or maybe /etc/ssh.